# Bash check if file matching regex exists and assign filename to variable

Tags: regex, bash

I'm looking for a fast, short and portable way to check if a file matching the regex `(env(ironment)?|requirements).ya?ml` exists in the current working directory and if so assign its basename to a variable `$FILE` for further processing.

Basically, I'd like to combine getting the handle in

```sh
for FILE in environment.yml env.yml requirements.yml environment.yaml env.yaml requirements.yaml; do
  if [ -e $FILE ]; then
    ...
  fi
done
```

with using a regex as in

```sh
if test -n "$(find -E . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*(env(ironment)?|requirements).ya?ml' -print -quit)"
then
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick it in a variable:

```
file="$(find -E . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*(env(ironment)?|requirements).ya?ml' -print -quit)"

if [ -n "$file" ]
then
  echo "I found $file"
else
  echo "No such file."
fi
```

Alternatively, you can keep your loop and shorten it using brace expansion:

```
for file in {env{,ironment},requirements}.{yml,yaml} 
do
  if [ -e "$file" ]
  then
    echo "Found $file"
  else
    echo "There is no $file"
  fi
done
```

or match files directly using bash's extglob:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in @(env?(ironment)|requirements).y?(a)ml
do
  echo "Found $file"
done
```

Comment: Does the first form (`test -n`) really work for multiple files?

Comment: @jpaugh Yes, though `test -e` wouldn't have. Due to the `-quit` it finds at most one file though

Comment: Missed that. Thanks!

Comment: "that other guy" knows more about scripting than I plan to! :-)